# How to convert integer str to integer in a nested list

Tags: python, loops, nested-lists

I have a nested list a:

```
a = [['fuzzy', '12'], ['drake', '6'], ['lebron', '23'], ['davis', '3'], ['jason', '16'], ['jon', '33'], ['jeff', '20'], ['rich', '33'], ['big', '100'], ['small', '2'], ['jack', '11'], ['queen', '12'], ['king', '13']]
```

I need to loop through this nested list and only change the integers strings into integers and the output should show

[['fuzzy', 12], ['drake', 6]....]

Any ideas?

Comment: Show us what output you get with what code you've tried so far.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `map` function:

```py
a = map(lambda x:[x[0], int(x[1])], a)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using list comprehension,

```
result = [[item[0], int(item[1])] for item in a]
```

Answer (score 0):

`for i in range(len(a)): a[i][1] = int(a[i][1])`

Just run through a loop and change the value with integers

Answer (score 0):

Do a for loop to run through each list, then reassign the second item in the list:

```
for pair in a:
   pair[1] = int(pair[1])
```